# select the text field of only one custom cell in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, keyboard

I have custom cells on a table view. All of the custom cells have one text field on them. The text fields start as disabled. I have configured them so that after a long press, the text fields become enabled and the user can edit the text field.

However, I would like the text fields to become enabled only one at a time so that the user doesn't have the option of switching to the text fields on other cells. So I would like to enable only the

Here is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        [cell.textField setEnabled:NO];

        //put in long press
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
    }
}
}
```

Then we have this:

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{

if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    // get affected cell
    cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[gesture view];

    // get indexPath of cell
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:0];

    // enabling text field
    [cell.textField setEnabled:YES];
    [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];

}
}
```

So as you can see, all of the text fields are enabled on the table view. How can I make only the table view of the selected cell active?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered adding the UILongPressGestureRecognizer to the cell's contentView in SimpleTableCell.m, rather than in your tableView.m?

Comment: Do you use [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SimpleTableCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier]; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with a simple solution. I made it so that I check to see if a text field is already active, and if it is not, then I enable the rest of the gesture method. And if the text field is enabled, then I cannot fire the gesture on any of the other cells. Works nicely as follows:

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
if (![cell.textField isEnabled]) {
// only when gesture was recognized, not when ended
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    // get affected cell
    cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[gesture view];

    // get indexPath of cell

    //NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[gesture locationInView:cell]];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:0];


    [cell.textField setEnabled:YES];
    [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is first hide all the textfields in cellForRowAtIndexPath then when long press longPress: method is called unhide the textfield for that particular cell then compare the indexpath if its the same as long press one then unhide

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

---------
if(indexPath.row == selectedIndexPathRow) {

   cell.textField.hidden = NO;   
    [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];

}
else {

   cell.textField.hidden = YES;
---------
}

- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{

if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    // get affected cell
    cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[gesture view];

    // get indexPath of cell
    selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    selectedIndexPathRow = selectedIndexPath.row;

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of enabling your text field's in the long press handler method, just use that method to select the cell, and then call reloadData. In your cellForRowAtIndexPath, have an if-else clause, and enable the text field if the index path is equal to the index path of the selected row, and disable it if it's not.

Comment: The trouble is, sometimes I want the user to be able to select the cell while still having the text field disabled. The idea is that selecting a cell loads a file into an audio player, and long pressing eventually renames the file via the text field.

Comment: @MScottWaller, then create a property which you set when the long press gesture handler is fired, and use that in cellForIndexPath (instead of the selectedCell) like I said in my answer. That way, you can still select the cell with a regular tap, and only enable the text field with a long press.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `NSIndexPath` creation as follows:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[gesture locationInView:cell]];
```